AWK: regex is not processed when passed as a variable
Any suggestions? I read: Escape Sequences (The GNU Awk User’s Guide)
Representative Example
$ Filesystem='/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Media'
$ FilesystemRegex="$(echo "${Filesystem}" | sed "s~/~\\\/~g")"
$ echo "$FilesystemRegex"
\/dev\/mapper\/vgubuntu-Media

$ df -H "${Filesystem}" | awk -v Regex="${FilesystemRegex}" '/$Regex/{print $5}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'

$ df -H "${Filesystem}" | awk '/\/dev\/mapper\/vgubuntu-Media/{print $5}'  
62%


See how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.

What you seem to be thinking of here, what with the escaped slashes and all, is straight up text replacement, something like re='foo\/bar'; awk "/$re/"' {print "match"}' where awk gets the script /foo\/bar/ {print "match"} after the shell expanded the variable. That may seem to "work", here, but mixing code and data like that is a bad idea, it gives you all sorts of quoting hell and is prone to creeping issues, possibly ones with security implications.

/$Regex/ is a regular expression that looks for Regex after the end of the subject ($) so can obviously never match.
To use an awk variable as a regexp, you can't use the /.../ operator which doesn't support embedding variables, you need:
$0 ~ variable

instead (also remember that the $ operator in awk is to dereference fields, it's not to reference variables like in shells).
To define that awk variable based on a shell variable, don't use -v as -v mangles blackslashes¹.
Instead, use an environment variable:
REGEX=$FilesystemRegex awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["REGEX"] {print $5}'

But here, it looks like you'd rather want:
df -- "$Filesystem" | FS=$Filesystem awk '$1 == ENVIRON["FS"] {print $5}'

-H is pointless since the 5th field² is a percentage.
Or to demonstrate the usage of the $ operator:
df -- "$Filesystem" | FS=$Filesystem awk -v fs_field=1 -v pcent_field=5 '
  $ fs_field == ENVIRON["FS"] {print $ pcent_field}'

Where $ here is applied to awk variables to retrieve the corresponding fields, the space is optional, you could use $fs_field or $ ( fs_field ) or $(fs_field * 1 + 0)...
In any case, / is not special in a regexp and doesn't need to be escaped. It only needs to be escaped when appearing literally inside the /.../ operator as otherwise it would be taken as the closing / of that operator.
The GNU implementation of df which your -H suggests you may be using also supports specifying which fields to include in the output.
So you could do:
df --output=pcent -- "$Filesystem" | tail -n+2

If on a Linux-based system, see also:
findmnt -no USE% -- "$Filesystem"


¹ By interpreting and substituting \x escape sequences, the same as in the strings of its own (or C's) syntax. Recent versions of GNU awk also mangle strings starting with @/ and /. For similar reasons, don't use echo
² Though that's not guaranteed to be the fifth as the first column could very well contain blanks.

If you want escape sequences interpreted then use (-v), if you don't then use ENVIRON[] or ARGV[]. IMO it's misleading to characterize -v interpreting escape sequences as "mangling" them since using -v is just a choice the user makes based on what they want awk to do given that assignment and what -v does is documented in the POSIX spec etc. as being the same as if you assigned a variable in the script. So, since awk 'BEGIN{ var="a\tb" }' interprets \t in the assignment, so does awk -v var="a\tb"

@EdMorton, it's just that it might be surprising that it modifies the value. IMO (and this may be subjective), it feels more common that backslash-escapes would only be interpreted within string constants in the code (though the shell's echo is a bit of an exception, maybe), but definitely not when just passing the value around. Arguably, that could be the shell's fault, I could imagine that AWK does the backslash processing there exactly because the shell doesn't do it in -v "\n" or whatever. Maybe "processing" would be a bit nicer word than "mangling", though...

@ilkkachu I agree that passing the value as-is would be more intuitive and I'd prefer if any interpreting was left up to the shell (-v var='a\tb' leaves \t while -v var=$'a\tb' creates a tab char). But, it is what it is and there are alternatives so my vote would just be for saying "interpreting" rather than "mangling" since it's just doing what it's designed and documented to do.

@EdMorton, see edit. In this context of "defining an awk variable based on a shell variable", I'd say "mangling" is a good enough characterisation. I want to make it clear that -v should not be used to pass arbitrary strings. Saying that -v var='a\tb' is right to interpret that \t because \t means TAB in the "strings" of awk's syntax, is a bit like saying that C's puts() for instance should expand those as well because \t means TAB in C's "strings".

I'm saying that every other way of assigning a string to a variable in awk, i.e. awk '{ var="a\tb" }' and awk '{ ... }' var='a\tb', also interpret \t so, while I agree it can be useful to give users a heads up that -v interprets escape sequences in case they havent thought about that, IMO referring to what -v does as "mangling" isnt accurate or useful as that sounds like some out of control trashing of the value when in fact -v is just behaving consistently with all other string assignments in interpreting escape sequences, and if you dont want that behavior there are alternatives.

In the context of "defining an awk variable based on a shell variable" the problem, I think, is that the code author doesnt know if the shell variable will include backslashes at run time, e.g. foo='a\tb$c', and so if they would rather not use ENVIRON[] or ARGV[], which are both cumbersome, then I believe they could just do awk -v var="${foo//\\/\\\\}" 'BEGIN{ printf "%s\n", var }' to escape any escapes but Im open to correction on that. I had originally thought -v "$(printf '%q' "$foo")" or -v "${foo@Q}" would work but the former also escapes $ while the latter just adds 's.

@EdMorton Doing ${foo//\\/\\\\} needs a ksh93-like shell (and neither $foo:gs/\/\\/ nor $foo:gs/\\/\\\\/ work in tcsh), and this kind of escaping is not fully safe as backslash is not the only character whose encoding contains byte 0x5c in some locales. And that doesn't cover gawk's @/.../ misfeature. In any case, not really simpler than using ENVIRON[]. Using ENVIRON[] is the best way here (also avoids leaking values on the command line), -v should be reserved for literal string constants.

@StéphaneChazelas I was referring to bash as that's what the OP is using. Good point about ENVIRON[] not leaking on the command line and the approach not working within @/.../ (and some day I'd like to understand why you refer to it as a misfeature - I asked once before when you said that but I suppose if I cared deeply enough I could just ask a question about it!).

@EdMorton see also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-10/msg00003.html and https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-10/msg00005.html in that same thread

Got it, thanks. Yeah, between that and { var="@/x/"; sub(/x/,foo) } to create a dynamic strongly typed regexp, that is kinda messy.
